# Defaulting new child files and folders to the parent folder ownership

Tags: permissions, files, directory, chmod, chown

I have created a directory and used chown to make my user and group the owner. If I create a new folder inside the parent folder then the permissions for 'others' under the permissions tab is set to 'access files' not 'create and delete files'.

How can I ensure all sub folders and files of my parent folder all default to the parent permissions?

Ubuntu 16.04LTS

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs directory
```

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115631/getting-new-files-to-inherit-group-permissions-on-linux

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the `setfacl` tool you can set this with:

```
sudo setfacl -R -d -m o::rwx /opt/lampp/htdocs
sudo setfacl -R -m o::rwx /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

The first line sets this to default, while the second just modifies and leaves the `acl` ( access control list ) values. The first line is what your looking for.

Info:

1. `-d`: default for future subfolders
2. `-m`: modify existing `acl`
3. `-R`: make changes recursively
4. `o`: set `acl` for folder others

See `man setfacl`

Comment: Thanks the first line worked great, can you just explain the second line a little further, why do I need it?

Comment: It does the same as the first only that it just modifies the `acl` but does not make it the default `acl` when a new subfolder is created.